# How to update an existing record in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to update an existing record in Django but whenever I PUT request with postman I get the following.

[image: Postman Request]

It says that it already exists. So i tried to assign

```
task_1 = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
task_1 = ser
```

But I get an error that i can't assign it

===============================

## My current code:

[image: models.py and urls.py]

```
class TaskView(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

        def put(self, request, task_id):
        task_obj = find_task(request.auth, task_id)
        if task_obj:
            task = task_obj.data
            my_data = json.loads(request.body)
            keys = list(my_data.keys())

            for key in keys:
                task[key] = my_data[key]

            ser = TaskSerializer(data=task)
            ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            ser.save()

            return Response(ser.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

# Returns the task only if its assigned to current user
def find_task(token, task_id):
    u_id = Token.objects.get(key=token).user_id
    assign_to = AssignTo.objects.filter(task_id=task_id, user_id=u_id)
    if len(assign_to) > 0:
        task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
        serializer = TaskSerializer(task)
        return serializer
    else:
        return False
```

I believe it has nothing to do with the method i use ( POST, PUT, PATCH) because it works perfect when I comment out this part of code:

```
            # ser = TaskSerializer(data=task)
            # print(ser)
            # ser.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            # ser.save()

            return Response(task)
```

So it's something with serialization and task Instances

===============================

## SECOND VERSION OF MY CODE:

```
    def put(self, request, task_id):
        u_id = Token.objects.get(key=request.auth).user_id
        assign_to = AssignTo.objects.filter(task_id=task_id, user_id=u_id)

        if len(assign_to) > 0:
            task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
            my_data = json.loads(request.body)
            keys = list(my_data.keys())

            for key in keys:
                task[key] = my_data[key]

            print(task)
            return Response(task)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

The error I get from my SECOND VERSION of code is :
`TypeError: 'Task' object does not support item assignment`

So how do I update JUST the given keys from the request body.

Comment: you can't reassign primary key of an object

Comment: May I know the reason why you're using post in the post instead of put for update and try to change the def post to put. Still, you are getting any issue post the models.py and serialize.py so that we can help you

Comment: @LinhNguyen I do not want to reassignin primary key. I just change some other attributes. But this is the question... I don't know how to update the Given keys only.

Comment: @Access_Doomer Many articles says that put and post are almost the same so i havent gave too much thought on that. Anyway, i changed it to put and still the same problem. The real question is how to update the GIVEN keys from the body.

Comment: can you show what is your input value in the postman request ? and what is id in the task model ? because it show "id" fields in your validation(which can only show the body data). To answer the previous you use put when you want to update a record and post when you want to create new record

Comment: @LinhNguyen I updated my question. Okay, thank you for highlighting the difference in post and put. I will keep it as PUT.

Comment: problem come from this line of code right here `ser = TaskSerializer(data=task)` can you try to print task before and see what it output ?

Comment: Have you tried ***`PATCH`*** request?

Comment: @LinhNguyen It seems pretty normal. It prints the Updated data
TaskSerializer (data={..my updated data..}):
 id = IntegerField(max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Task.objects.all())>])
    task_type_id = IntegerField(allow_null=True, max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False) )

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I tried now. Same results!!

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was pretty simple.

I just had to add some args inside the save function => task.save(update_fields=keys)

This is my working code:

```
    def put(self, request, task_id):
        # task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
        # Task is the returned Model value
        task = find_task(request.auth, task_id)
        if task:
            my_data = json.loads(request.body)
            keys = list(my_data.keys())

            for key in keys:
                setattr(task, key, my_data[key])

            task.save(update_fields=keys)
            ser = TaskSerializer(task)
            return Response(ser.data)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```